# Disable the Child Div By the nth Parent Div

Tags: jquery, html

In the End of Question, I have Given my div structure. I have added this div by dynamically. So Somehow I get the patent id of dynamically created div. So now on I want to disable or hide that input inside the id which is "forth-three-one".

I can not use this id "forth-three-one" directly to hide the input because it affects the other input which has the same id.

I have tried this Jquery.

```
$('#the-patent-id').parents().eq(4).addclass("hidden");
```

But not getting the desired result.

So How can I Disable the Child Div By the "nth" Parent Div element?

```
<div id="patent-1">

        <div class="one"></div>

        <div class="two"></div>

        <div class="three"></div>

        <div class="forth">

            <div class="forth-one"></div>

            <div class="forth-two"></div>

            <div class="forth-three">

                <div class="forth-three-one">
                <input type="redio" name = "By clicing this radio" class="isCurrentClass">
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-two">
                <input>
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-three">
                <input type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
                </div>


             </div>                     

        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the Actual scenario, and the Actual js I have written. I am Disabling the input on click of the input inside.

```
$(document).on('click','.isCurrentClass',function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }

    var id = $(".isCurrentClass").closest("div").prop("class");
    alert(id);

    alert($('.isCurrentClass').parents().eq(4).attr("id"));

    var ank = $('.isCurrentClass').parents().eq(4).attr("id");

    $("#".ank).find('div:eq(3) > div:eq(2) > div:first-child input').prop('disabled', 'true');

});
```

Comment: *I can not use this id "forth-three-one" directly to hide the input because it affects the other input which has the same id.* Two elements can not have the same id

Comment: Btw, the id selector is `#`, not `.`

Comment: I have dynamically created this div so if I use the id or class which are same for all the input.

Comment: I changed that. Thanks but still the problem is not solved.

Comment: So, in your example, would `div.three` have the same child element structure as `div.forth`?

Comment: Yes sir  @Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `eq()` selector as below:

*Note*: ID selector should start with `#` and `ID` should be unique to the element and more than one elements should not share the same id.

**Answer 1**: (As you requested)

```js
$(document).on('click','.isCurrentClass', function () {
    /*if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }

    var id = $(".isCurrentClass").closest("div").prop("class");
    alert(id);

    alert($('.isCurrentClass').parents().eq(4).attr("id"));

    var ank = $('.isCurrentClass').parents().eq(4).attr("id");

    $("#".ank).find('div:eq(3) > div:eq(2) > div:first-child input').prop('disabled', 'true');*/
    
    $(this).parents().eq(3).find('div:eq(3) > div:eq(2) > div:eq(2) > input').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div id="patent-1">

        <div class="one"></div>

        <div class="two"></div>

        <div class="three"></div>

        <div class="forth">

            <div class="forth-one"></div>

            <div class="forth-two">

            </div>

            <div class="forth-three">

                <div class="forth-three-one">
                   <input type="radio" name = "By clicing this radio" class="isCurrentClass">
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-two">
                   <!--<input>-->
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-three">
                   <input type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
                </div>


             </div>                     

        </div>

    </div>
```

**Answer 2**: (Generic Solution)

```js
$(document).on('click','.isCurrentClass', function () {
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find('div:eq(2) > input').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div id="patent-1">

        <div class="one"></div>

        <div class="two"></div>

        <div class="three"></div>

        <div class="forth">

            <div class="forth-one"></div>

            <div class="forth-two">
              <div class="forth-two-one">
                   <input type="radio" name = "By clicing this radio" class="isCurrentClass">
                </div>

                <div class="forth-two-two">
                   <!--<input>-->
                </div>

                <div class="forth-two-three">
                   <input type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="forth-three">

                <div class="forth-three-one">
                   <input type="radio" name = "By clicing this radio" class="isCurrentClass">
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-two">
                   <!--<input>-->
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-three">
                   <input type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
                </div>


             </div>                     

        </div>

    </div>
```

**Answer 3**: (Refactored Generic solution to allow only one textbox disabled corresponding to the radio button checked)

```js
$(document).on('change','.isCurrentClass', function () {

    $(this).parents().eq(2).find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    
    $(this).parents().eq(1).find('div:eq(2) > input').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div id="patent-1">

        <div class="one"></div>

        <div class="two"></div>

        <div class="three"></div>

        <div class="forth">

            <div class="forth-one"></div>

            <div class="forth-two">
              <div class="forth-two-one">
                   <input type="radio" name = "By clicing this radio" class="isCurrentClass">
                </div>

                <div class="forth-two-two">
                   <!--<input>-->
                </div>

                <div class="forth-two-three">
                   <input type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="forth-three">

                <div class="forth-three-one">
                   <input type="radio" name = "By clicing this radio" class="isCurrentClass">
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-two">
                   <!--<input>-->
                </div>

                <div class="forth-three-three">
                   <input type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
                </div>


             </div>                     

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I have Edited the question, Sir but not able to disable the input

Comment: @ankitsuthar I have updated my answer with class instead of id as you edited. If you click the button "Run code snippet" under my answer, it will disable the textbox. You can use `#patent-1` instead of  `#the-patent-id` which you used in your question. So, finally you can use something like `$('#patent-1 > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) input').prop('disabled', true);` to disable the textbox as in my answer.

Comment: @ankitsuthar Where is the element having `.isCurrentClass`  class in your html? Can you edit your html?

Comment: I have Edited the Question, sir.

Comment: You can check answer 1, 2 & 3 above in my updated answer and let me know which fits you..

Comment: the 3rd answer useful.  I have also given the answer in which I add the script which helps me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#patent-1').find('#forth-three-one input').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="patent-1">

        <div id="one"></div>

        <div id="two"></div>

        <div id="three"></div>

        <div id="forth">

            <div id="forth-one"></div>

            <div id="forth-two"></div>

            <div id="forth-three">

                <div id="forth-three-one">
                <input name = "I want to disable this input" />
                </div>

             </div>                     

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have same ids and you should use classes instead, but other than that you can select that input starting from parent using indexes with selector like this.

```js
$('#patent-1').find('div:eq(3) > div:eq(2) > div:first input').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().siblings().eq(1).find('input').prop('disabled', 'true');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="patent-1">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="forth">
    <div class="forth-one"></div>
    <div class="forth-two"></div>
    <div class="forth-three">
      <div class="forth-three-one">
        <input type="radio" name="By clicing this radio">
      </div>
      <div class="forth-three-two">
        <input>
      </div>
      <div class="forth-three-three">
        <input type="text" name="I want to disable this input">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `.siblings()`

With the following structure:

```
<div class="forth-three">
    <div class="forth-three-one radio-container">
        <input class="my-radio" type="radio" name="By clicking this radio">
    </div>
    <div class="forth-three-two">
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="forth-three-three input-container">
        <input class="my-input" type="text" name = "I want to disable this input">
    </div>
</div>
```

your jquery could be as simple as...

```
$(document).on('click', '.my-radio', function(){
    var $radio = $(this);
    var $input = $radio.parents('.radio-container')
        .siblings('.input-container')
        .find('.my-input');

    if ($radio.is(':checked')){
        $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }else{
        $input.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

For reference on `.siblings()` see: https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: No sir i am not updating id here.

Answer (score 0):

This the Solution Which helps me to hide the input.

```
        // No I take the model id tho check that which radio button is not  checked , so I can make there input visible.

        $(document).on('click','#custom-modal-experience',function () {

        var unchkDivIds = $('.isCurrentClass:not(":checked")').map(function(){
            return $(this).parents().eq(4).attr("id");        
              }).get();
        arrayUnchkDivIds = $.makeArray(unchkDivIds);
        // console.log("unchced array: "+arrayUnchkDivIds);

        // By using each here we remove the hidden class form all unchcked div
        $.each( arrayUnchkDivIds, function( i, val ) {
            //console.log (i +" : " + val);  
            $("#"+val).find('.endDateHiddenYes').removeClass('hidden');
            });

        });

        // Get the parent id by clicking on the radio button. 

        $(document).on('click','.isCurrentClass',function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //alert($(this).val());
        }              
        var parentDivId = $(this).parents().eq(4).attr("id");      
        $("#"+parentDivId).find('.endDateHiddenYes').addClass('hidden');                
        });
```

Process: First I Have the Div Structure as I Mention in the question. 
Then After the add button, I will add the same div structure below the div structure. 
Now Came to Radio button. I want to hide the input on click of the radio button.
So first I get the Parent id of the Div structure which I got by the radio button click.

So After getting the parent div id, I will disable the chile input by that.

But in this process I want to allow user to only select one radio so other radio buttons input have to came visible.